# Images that I uploaded through WebAPI via FTP are not accessible in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, ftp

I have an MVC site which places images on a page like:

```
    @foreach (var itm in Model)
{
    {
        <img class="images" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 15px;"
         src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" />
    }
}
```

Previously it has not been intended to support adding of images and so all ImageUrl's pointed to a place holder silhouette photo. Now however I am uploading the images via my API over FTP.

The images were on the server, with the page referring to precisely the correct site location for each image, however the images weren't found like they didn't exist. The location is DEFINITELY correct as the place holder silhouette image displays correctly.

I then added the images into my VS project and did a publish and weirdly that worked, the images now displayed fine.

This obviously doesn't solve the problem as the API should store the images in the site without me having to publish from VS every time!

I publish the images to FTP like:

```
public static bool ftpTransfer(string fileName, byte[] image)
{
     byte[] buffer = image;
     string ftpAddress = "xxxxx";
     string username = "xxxxx";
     string password = "xxxxx";

     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ftpAddress + "/" + "site" + "/" + "wwwroot" + "/" + "Content" + "/" + "images" + "/" + fileName);
     request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
     Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
     reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     reqStream.Close();

return true;
}
```

So what is going on and why doesn't the `src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl"` find the image until I publish, despite it being in the folder?

Comment: Your question includes a lot of irrelevant info and lacks relevant info. So the core problem is _"Images that I uploaded through WebAPI are not accessible in MVC"_?

Comment: Sorry. hope that's better. I thought it relevant that they appeared after I published from VS

Comment: I mean you should show some relevant code or explanation of how your uploading process works. Obviously the problem lies there.

Comment: What does `src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl"` give you in the rendered page?  It looks like you've combined `~` and `@`, which Razor doesn't tend to like much.

Comment: @freedomn-m NOW it gives me the correct image. But it only does this after I have published from VS.

Comment: @CodeCaster Will post that code now

Comment: If they worked when you added them to the VS+publish, but don't work when you upload via api/ftp, then either you're uploading to the wrong folder (which I assume you've checked that they do actually exist in the images folder after uploading) or, more likely, your folder *permissions* are incorrect and asp.net or the `IIdentity` that your app pool is running under does not have access to the uploaded files.

Comment: Correct image / correct url are not the same thing - what's the value of "src" in the rendered html (when it's not working) - not what's the image look like in the browser (sorry, my bad for saying 'rendered page' - I meant html output as opposed to razor .cshtml)

Comment: As an aside, you really shouldn't upload data directly into your images folder from a third party app (api/ftp).  When you upgrade your website by re-publishing, all the user data (images) will be lost.

Comment: @freedomn-m They are definitely in the correct location. The thing is my site clearly has the permissions as it displays them fine once published via VS, and surely my API has permissions as they appear on the server when I FTP in to check.

Comment: @freedomn-m Can you suggest what would be the best method for receiving images relating to a data entity via an API so that they become visible on the site in a completely automated fashion then?

Comment: If you publish via VS, then they have the permissions of the publisher (probably you).  If you upload via API/FTP then they will have the permissions of the API/FTP service account.  When you browse the site, it will be using the IIS app pool permissions (not yours).  If you can see them then you have both permissions.   There's nothing that confirms the IIS appool account can see files created by the API service - different "users" (service accounts) see different files.

Comment: @freedomn-m Okay thanks, that's probably it. Is there a way of fixing that issue, or if not how can I store the images in the site when I receive them via API.

Comment: What I've personally done in the past with situations like this is simply pick some network location accessible to both sites and create a virtual directory pointing there in both sites in IIS. Give the IIS user access to read and write to that directory and you're off to the races. No FTP needed.